# Is It possible to display multiple item in Ext.JS Card Layout

Tags: extjs, sencha-architect

One of my new project i need to show 5 graph in a page. But at the same time i need to display only 2 item. So i use Card layout. But it only allow me to set only one item as an active item. Is it possible to set more than one active item.

Answer (score 0):

Card layout will only display one of its children at a time. You should probably use another layout that arranges your charts as you want (for example `vbox` layout), and show/hide them selectively.

Another option would be to nest your charts into containers, themselves in the card layout, but that won't give you the possibility to display any combination of chart... But only the ones you've put together in a container.

You containers would be configured something like this:

```
Ext.widget('container', {
    layout: 'card'
    ,items: [{
        xtype: 'container'
        ,layout: 'vbox'
        ,items: [{
            xtype: 'myChart1'
        },{
            xtype: 'myChart2'
        }]
    },{
        xtype: 'container'
        ,layout: 'vbox'
        ,items: [{
            xtype: 'myChart3'
        },{
            xtype: 'myChart4'
        }]
    },{
        xtype: 'myChart5'
    }]
});
```